# can someone help me pick out the particular field?

Tags: unix, command-line-interface

I have to generate a script that alerts me when disk space goes beyond a threshold.

`df -k` command would fetch me the disc spaces involved in my working directory.

For example,the output would be

```
 Filesystem    1024-blocks      Free %Used    Iused %Iused Mounted on
  /dev/hd4            32768     16016   52%     2271    14% /
  /dev/hd2          4587520   1889420   59%    37791     4% /usr
  /dev/hd9var         65536     12032   82%      518     4% /var
  /dev/hd3           819200    637832   23%     1829     1% /tmp
  /dev/hd1           524288    395848   25%      421     1% /home
  /proc                   -         -    -         -     -  /proc
  /dev/hd10opt        65536     26004   61%      654     4% /opt
```

Here, I need to pick out one particular file system,say /dev/hd9var,in that I need to check %value of Iused. If the value goes beyond the threshold, a mail alert has to come thro . .Help me achieve it. I tried awk but cant the value for one particualr row..

Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: _I tried awk but cant the value for one particualr row..._ --> Why not pass it as an argument to the `df -k`.

Answer (score 1):

```
df -k /var |awk '{print $4}'

df -k |awk '$1 == "/dev/hd9var" {print $4}'

df -k /var |awk '$3 < 1000 { system(send email)}'

df -k /var |awk '$4 ~ /9.%/ || $4 == "100%" { system(send email)}'
```